# wpf user control initialization

Tags: .net, wpf

I was initializing user control usnig xaml code and it's worked just fine.

```
<my:TreassureControl x:Name="treassureControl" Visibility="Hidden" AfterBackClick="controls_AfterBackClick" />
```

Now I want to pass instance of repository to my control and I was thinking to move initialization of user control from xaml to code

So I tried to put inside `MainWindow()` constructor after `InitializationComponent();`

```
treassureControl = new Controls.TreassureControl();
treassureControl.AfterBackClick += controls_AfterBackClick;
```

but using this I'm gettng empty window without loaded control.

What I'm doing wrong? Or is it possible to send parameter to user control inside xaml code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the control as the window's content.

```
treassureControl = new Controls.TreassureControl();
treassureControl.AfterBackClick += controls_AfterBackClick;
this.Content = treassureControl;
```